# Yii 1.1.8 - Error messages without line numbers

Tags: error-handling, yii

I have a simple issue "Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated", but I am not sure where to go to fix it.

How do I enable line numbers to show?

Answer (score 0):

you can activate the debug function in main.php file. This file located in protected/config folder.

Edit as following:

1. locate the 'log' array inside the file
2. uncomment the CWebLogRoute in the array

If you do it right, then when error shows up, you can see the error location.

[How your main.php log config looks like when uncomment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Snc.png)